# showing specific xtick in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I have a graph that runs on an order of magnitude 10000 time steps, and thus I have a lot of data points and the xticks are spaced pretty far apart, which is cool, but I would like to to show on the xaxis the point at which the data is being plotted. In this case the xtick I want to show is 271. So is there a way to just "insert" 271 tick onto the x axis given that I already know what tick I want to display?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If it's not important that the ticks update when panning/zomming (i.e. if the plot is not meant for interactive use), then you can manually set the tick locations with the [`axes.set_xticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) method. In order to append one location (e.g. `271`), you can first get the current tick locations with [`axes.get_xticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks), and then append `271` to this array.

A short example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.arange(300))

# Get current tick locations and append 271 to this array
x_ticks = np.append(ax.get_xticks(), 271)

# Set xtick locations to the values of the array `x_ticks`
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks)

plt.show()
```

This produces

[image: Axes with added tick location]

As you can see from the image, a tick has been added for `x=271`.

Comment: Thank you, Also is there an easy way to get a vertical dashed line about that tick too?

Comment: @NedU Do you want a line only at this tickmark, or at all tickmarks? If you want it only at x=271, you can use `ax.axvline(271, ls='--')`. If you want lines for all tickmarks (on x-axis), you can use `ax.grid(axis='x')`.